At the time of implementing pipe in the ngrx it is showing error Angular 18
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
this is the code I have written
register$ = createEffect(():any=>{
    this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(registerUser),
    mergeMap(action=>
      this.userService.userRegister(action.firstName,action.lastName,action.email,action.phone,action.password).pipe(
        map(user=> registerUserSuccess({user:user}))
      )
     ) 
   )
 })

export class UserService {

  constructor(private readonly apollo: Apollo) {  
  }
   userRegister(firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string,phone:number,password:string):Observable<any>  {
    return this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: REGISTER_USER,
      variables: { userInput: { firstName, email, lastName, phone, password } },
    }) 
   
  } 

How to solve this problem

Can you add the code where this.actions$ is initialized? Also can you add the code of the userRegister function?

constructor(
private readonly actions$: Actions,
private userService:UserService,
private cookieService:CookieService
) {}
here I initailzed

Can you edit the question and add the code of the userRegister function from UserService?

I edited my code provided the code of service

@SarathS please replicate the issue in this stackblitz and share back

When creating an effect, you must return an Observable. Currently you are not returning anything. Either remove the curly braces:
register$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  // ... rest of code
));

Or leave the curly braces and add a return statement:
register$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    // ... rest of code
  );
});

TypeScript has warned you about it, but you have ignored it by adding any type. Most of the times it is better to listen to TypeScript.

I tried both way it also showing the errror

The same error, or a different one?

same error I am using angular 18 and no standalone

Add the following in tsconfig.json:
"compilerOptions": {
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
